# Tables do not align side by side

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

[image]

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}%\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & One & Twp & Three \\
 \hline
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & One & Twp & Three \\
 \hline
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to create two tables side by side and in the PDF they do not appear aligned. Second table is slightly lower than the first one, I have no clue how to fix it.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}%\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & One & Twp & Three \\
\hline
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & One & Twp & Three \\
 \hline
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just came across this question while retagging. Could you tell me what the difference between your solution and Aku's original code is? I can't find one (except for the added `\documentclass` and `{document}`).

Comment: @Caramdir don't really remember if there was a marginal difference. Looking at TH's answer also it was just working code, so I probably just created the minimal or the OP edited the question?

Comment: Can we have single caption for both of the tables?

Answer (score 8):

Problems:

- Your tables exceed the text width, because you use two times `0.5\linewidth` plus `\hspace{0.5cm}`. This can cause alignment problems and is problematic in general.
- You align minipages at the bottom, using `[b]`, not at the top. I guess that's because of the caption, but this way you don't control the top.

I suggest:

- Always take care of the line width resp. text width. Note: also line breaks or blanks between minipages count and require space. Insert `%` before an end of the line to prevent that.
- Use the optional height argument of `minipage` or `\parbox`. You could use a fixed height, top alignment (below `pos`, `inner-pos`), perhaps `\vfill` to achieve alignment at top and bottom (captions).

  Syntax: `\begin{minipage}[pos][height][inner-pos]{width}`
- Further tip: vertical lines are really distracting. For me, some horizontal lines are usually fine. I strongly recommend to use the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. Just look into good books to see for yourself that fine tables don't interrupt rows by vertical lines.

Comment: All good advice!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work just fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\noindent
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & One & Twp & Three \\
 \hline
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & One & Twp & Three \\
 \hline
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 2}
}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This wasn't part of your question, but I think if you follow the advice given in the `booktabs` documentation, you can produce even better looking tables. Compare.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\noindent
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{One}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Two}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Three} \\
\midrule
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
}%
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{One}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Two}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Three} \\
\midrule
1 & Subject A: & Subject A & Subject  \\
2 & Subject B & Subject B& Subject  \\
3 & Subject C & Subject C & Subject   \\
4 & Subject D & Subject D & Subject  \\
4 & Subject E & Subject E & Subject   \\
5 &Subject F & Subject F & Subject  \\
6 & Subject G & Subject G & Subject  \\
7 &Subject H &Subject H &Subject   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table 2}
}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```